# How to use VBA .SaveAs by copying a number from a cell in the spreadsheet retaining a particular number format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

In Cell A1, I have the number (56,000), which is -56000 (negative fifty-six thousand), formatted as Accounting. However, whenever I use VBA to include that cell value in the filename, it saves it as "Test-56000.xlms" instead of "Test(56,000).xlms". How do I make it retain the number formatting?

```
Sub MyTest()

    TestFile = Dir("C:\Users\webcamz\Desktop\TEST\Test.xlsx")

    If TestFile <> "" Then
        Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\webcamz\Desktop\TEST\Test.xlsx"
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\webcamz\Desktop\TEST\Test" & Range("A1").Value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work and use the converted string variable in the filename.

```
Dim str As String
If Range("A1").Value < 0 Then
    str = "(" & Abs(Range("A1")) & ")"
Else
    str = Range("A1").Value
End If
```